# Python how to loop with enumerate

Tags: python, loops, enumerate

I want convert that code from numers ex:

```
animal = ["Dog1","Dog2","Dog3"]
```

to names of animals.

```
def start():
    animal = ["Dog","Cat","Bird"]
    index = 0
    max_value = max(animal)
    max_index = animal.index(max_value)
    for index, animal in enumerate(animal):
        while True:
            if index <= max_index:
                print(animal, index, "Max index: ",max_index)
            break
    start()    
    print("Fresh loop!")
```

How to do that, and how delete start() in while loop? I want

```
if index == max_index:
```

refresh loop.
That code works with

```
["Dog1","Dog2","Dog3"]
```

but not work with

```
["Dog","Cat","Bird"]
```

Comment: First things first. `type` is a keyword in python, so you should not be using that to name your variables. Second `enumerate` loops over an iterator and gives the index and element at that index in each iteration. Maybe you should fix these things first

Comment: Don’t call start() to restart the function. That’s recursion, uses stack memory and will eventually cause a failure. Use a while loop.

Comment: My fault with "type" when post it here. I change it on "animal"

Comment: with if index == max_index+1: it execute only ounce because, that if condition never get true. max index in 2 and you are trying to check if 2 == 3, which will give false and only the else part is executed

Comment: I edit my post. did You know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark Tolonen commented, I too strongly recommend to not use the start in the if condition to avoid infinite loop

```
def start():
    animal = ["site1","site2","site3"]
    index = 0
    max_value = max(animal)
    max_index = animal.index(max_value)
    for index, animal in enumerate(animal):
        print(animal, index, "Max index: ",max_index)
        if index == max_index:
            print("Fresh loop!")
            start()

start()
```

Output:

```
site1 0 Max index:  2
site2 1 Max index:  2
site3 2 Max index:  2
Fresh loop!
site1 0 Max index:  2
site2 1 Max index:  2
site3 2 Max index:  2
Fresh loop!
...
```

Second Requirement: using while loop

```
def start():
    animal = ["Dog", "Cat", "Rat"]
    index = 0
    max_value = max(animal)
    max_index = animal.index(max_value)
    while index <= max_index:
        print(animal[index], index, "Max index: ",max_index)
        index = index + 1
        if index == len(animal):
            print("Fresh loop!")
            index = 0

start()
```

or you can even do it this way

```
def start(animal):
    index = 0
    max_value = max(animal)
    max_index = animal.index(max_value)
    while index <= max_index:
        print(animal[index], index, "Max index: ",max_index)
        index = index + 1
        if index == len(animal):
            print("Fresh loop!")
            index = 0

animal = ["Dog", "Cat", "Rat"]
start(animal)
```

Output:

```
Dog 0 Max index:  2
Cat 1 Max index:  2
Rat 2 Max index:  2
Fresh loop!
...
```

Comment: Thanks with second while loop. It works fine! But how add to this function, when max_index = 3 (finish loop) refresh loop without do start()?i can do that with start() but how to do without it?  if index == 3:
            print("Fresh loop!")
            start()

Answer (score 0):

calling your function`start` in itself makes infinite loop

```
if index == max_index:
            print("Fresh loop!")
            start()
```